# My listview dosen't appear

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a RSS feed through a listView with an AsyncTask and a Custom Adapter.
The problem is ,when i execute my code .It start well but my screen activity stay empty ,no listview ,an ANR either.I want to understand why nothing appear and how I can fix it.Someone tell me my problem is caused by me custom adapter but I don't see any error in it.
myMainActivity 's is below:

```
 ListView listView;

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;
Document document;
Element element;
NodeList listdenoeud;


//string recup d'info html
private int nbrArticle;
private String strurl;
public String titre="";
public String description="";
public String liens="";
public String urlimage="";
ArrayList<NoeudItems> listTitre;
BackgroundTask backgroundTask;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    strurl="http://www.lemonde.fr/m-actu/rss_full.xml";
    backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(strurl);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_itemx);

    if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        ListAdapter listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplication(),listTitre);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,AsyncTask.Status>{
    @Override
    protected Status doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            //lecture du fichier xml et ajout dans la bdd
            documentBuilderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder=documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document=documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(strurl));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            listdenoeud=document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int i = 0;
            //boucle de recuperation des attribues des noeuds situer dans le xml
            while ( listdenoeud.getLength()!=i ) {
                Node noeud=listdenoeud.item(i);
                if(noeud.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    element = (Element) noeud;
                    listTitre = new ArrayList<NoeudItems>();
                    liens = element.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent();
                    titre = element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent();
                    urlimage = element.getElementsByTagName("enclosure").item(0).getAttributes().item(2).getTextContent();
                    description = element.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //foutu bug de la methode si-dessous
                    listTitre.add(new NoeudItems(titre, description, urlimage, liens));
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("fin du thread","je passe ici");
        return Status.FINISHED;
     }
    }
  }
```

and my Custom Adapter's code is below:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Bitmap bitmap;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context cContext;
 ArrayList<NoeudItems> list=new ArrayList<>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<NoeudItems> e){
    this.list=e;
    this.cContext=context;
    this.inflater=inflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public NoeudItems getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    HolderView holderView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, parent, false);

        holderView.imageArticle = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageArticle);
        holderView.textTitre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitre);
        holderView.textDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textviewdescription);

        holderView.textTitre.setText(list.get(i).titre);
        holderView.textDescription.setText(list.get(i).description);
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(list.get(i).strbitmap).openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            bitmap = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holderView.imageArticle.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        convertView.setTag(holderView);
    }
    else{
        holderView = (HolderView) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class HolderView{
    ImageView imageArticle;
    TextView textTitre;
    TextView textDescription;
  }
}


   public class NoeudItems {
String titre;
String description;
String strbitmap;
ArrayList<String> url;
```

and my NoeudItem's code:

```
public class NoeudItems {

String titre;
String description;
String strbitmap;
ArrayList<String> url;


public  NoeudItems (String title,String descrip,String strbtmp,String urlLiens){
    url=new ArrayList<String>();
    titre=title;
    description=descrip;
    url.add(urlLiens);}

public String getTitre(){
    return titre; }
public String getDescription(){
    return description; }
public String geturl(){
    return strbitmap; } }
```

can someone tell me where I make a mistake or what's wrong in my code?

Comment: This is really a **W-E-I-R-D** usage of the AsyncTask Object: `if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){`. You really should use its `onPostExecute()` method, instead. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Return list of RssItems from doInBackground
- Override onPostExecute of AsyncTask
- In onPostExecute Method, check if List returned by doInBackground is not null
- Pass the list if not null e.g. listTitre to your CustomAdapter class
- Else Show a Toast that no list is returned

Comment: I did all these test and the toast show me the size of listTitre and it's not null.the toast show 20.so i guess it's not my caused by my arraylist

Comment: Where is NoeudItems.class? Could you post it if possible?

Comment: `public class NoeudItems {

    String titre;
    String description;
    String strbitmap;
    ArrayList<String> url;


    public  NoeudItems (String title,String descrip,String strbtmp,String urlLiens){
        url=new ArrayList<String>();
        titre=title;
        description=descrip;
        url.add(urlLiens);
   }
}

Comment: Use Setter and Getter in your class.  Use Setter in the loop while getting Values from the Node and Getters in your Adapter Class

Comment: if I use setter ine the loop while getting values ,I should use another constructor because listTitre will be useless ,is it right?

Comment: You can use setter or just Constructor. It is OK how you did it already. Just use getter in your adapter to fetch values. Also, I don't think you need NoeudItems class in your adapter

Comment: finally i use the getter from my NoeudItems class in my adapter but still have the same problem ,I can see only the first item.

Comment: Update your adapter and I will see if in can help. Although you can do this for(into k = 0; k < listTitre.size(); k++) { // get your data here E.g. NoeudItems items = (NoeudItems) listTitre.get(k);  //now get all you values from items e.g. TextView.setText(items.getTitle() )}

Answer (score 0):

It's because this piece of code

```
if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        ListAdapter listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplication(),listTitre);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
```

doesn't execute the way you expect. It's there to identify the `AsyncTasks`'s status at a given time, and not be used as a callback when the async task has finished executing. You must override `onPostExecute()` in the `AsyncTask` class and return the results back to the `Activity` and then populate the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code, in `onCreate`:

```
backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
backgroundTask.execute(strurl);
if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    ListAdapter listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplication(),listTitre);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

`backgroundTask.execute(strurl);` always run in a thread, that means we dont know how long it take to finish this `AsyncTask`. Therefore, the checking block `if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)` will be executed before your `Task` finish.
So, how to overcome it? Just implement `onPostExecute` in your `Task` and check the `result` to create new `Adapter` and set to listview.

Comment: now the listView appear but it weird because i can see only the first item.

Comment: @litv you should log the size of your listview in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score -2):

In place of,

```
if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    ListAdapter listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplication(),listTitre);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Try,

```
if (backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
    ListAdapter listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplication(),listTitre);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: This achieves nothing in this case.